Chain rule for Jacobian of computation graph
I'm currently reading about automatic differentiation and I've come across two questions while attempting it in a dummy 1d example.
In the feed forward derivative case things make sense, you can apply the chain rule easily. However, I was then interested in differentiating with respect to the "learnable parameters" of my function, the toy function I was looking at is:
$$
f(x, W) = w_1sin(w_2cos(x))
$$
For the normal feedforward case with x of arbitrary dimension the chain rule would allow you to compute the jacobian matrix of x by matrix product. For example:
$$
\partial_xf(x)= \partial_x(w_1sin(x))|_{x = w_2cos(x)} * \partial_x(w_2cos(x))|_{x = x}
$$
However for the case of the jacobian matrix w.r.t. $W$ I find that the dimensionality of the matrices no longer match up. A simpler example I've thought of is the following and it raises the same question for me:
$$
f(x) = x_1sin(x_2cos(x_1))
$$
What should the intermediate jacobian matrices look like in these cases? I've only been able to find very simple examples (e.g a matrix product) to show a Jacobian, I think seeing what the above should look like would be helpful.
A direct solution that comes to mind is to include the "hidden" input space in the output but that feels weird and kind of forced.

Why the title talks about a "computation graph"?

you can decompose the function into multiple simple functions that form a graph.

I think, you can consider these two functions: $h:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by $h(w_1, w_2)=(w_1, w_2\cos (x))$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(z_1, z_2)=z_1\sin (z_2)$. I am assuming that $x$ is constant, since they are not learnable parameters, and therefore it would not make sense to differentiate with respect to them. Note that $f(w_1, w_2) = w_1\sin(w_2 \cos (x))$ is equal to $g\circ h(w_1, w_2)$. And therefore we have:
$$\partial f(w) = \partial g(h(w))\partial h(w)=   \nabla g(h(w))^\top \partial h(w) $$ where $w=(w_1, w_2)$, $\partial h (w) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & cos(x)
\end{bmatrix}$ and  $\nabla g(h(w))^\top = [\sin (w_2 \cos x ), w_1\cos(w_2\cos x)]$.

For your "simpler example"
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\q{\quad}     \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\d{\delta}
x &= \pmatrix{v\\w} \qiq v=e_1^Tx
,\q w=e_2^Tx
,\q e_k=\grad{x}{x_k}
,\q e_j^Te_k=\d_{jk}
\\\\
f(x) &= v\,\sin\!\big(w\,\cos(v)\big)
 \;\equiv\; (e_1^T\c x)\,\sin\!\big((e_2^T\c x)\,\cos(e_1^T\c x)\big) \\
\\
\grad f{x_k}
  &=\, (e_1^T\c{e_k})\,\sin\!\big(w\,\cos(v)\big) 
+ v\,\sin\!\big((e_2^T\c{e_k})\,\cos(v)\big) 
+ v\,\sin\!\big(w\,\cos(e_1^T\c{e_k})\big) \\
\\
\grad fx
  &= \left[\matrix{ 
\sin\!\big(w\,\cos(v)\big) + 0 + v\,\sin\!\big(w\,\cos({\tt1})\big) \\
0 + v\,\sin\!\big(\cos(v)\big) + v\,\sin\!\big(w\big) \\
}\right]
}$$
